# static variable is null after initialization

Tags: android, static, android-listfragment

I have an action bar activity with 3 tabs.
I have a main activity, where I post an xml to a webservice and get back an xml in an AsyncTaskj. I'm initializing a static variable of the main activity in AsncTask. From main activity another activity is called, where Action Bar is initialized. Each action bar has a ListFragment, where I use the static variable. I have no issue accessing a Static variable from 2 List activities but in first ListFragment m not able to access the initialized static variable.

**Edit 1**

My Main Activity

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GenerateXml gx=new GenerateXml();
            String requestXml=gx.generateXml(tv1.getText().toString(),tv2.getText().toString(),tv3.getText().toString(),tv4.getText().toString());
            myNewTask = new MyTask(requestXml);
            myNewTask.execute();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TabActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In my AsyncTask doInBackground

```
MainActivity.responseXml=responseXML;
```

The Activity where tabs are created

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {
    MyTask myNewTask;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        /** Creating All Tab */
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("All")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<AllMsgFragment>(this, "All", AllMsgFragment.class));
        //.setIcon(R.drawable.android);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);


        /** Creating Success Tab */
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Success")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<SuccessMsgFragment>(this, "Success", SuccessMsgFragment.class));
        //.setIcon(R.drawable.apple);


        actionBar.addTab(tab);   

        /** Creating Error Tab */
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Error")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<ErrorMsgFragment>(this, "error", ErrorMsgFragment.class));
        //.setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

My first ListFragment:

```
public class AllMsgFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static String response;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> msgDetails;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        response=MainActivity.responseXml;
        XmlToArrayList xmlArray=new XmlToArrayList();
        try {
            msgDetails=xmlArray.arrayListXml(response);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), msgDetails,
                R.layout.msg_preview,
                new String[] { "ObSystem", "ObName", "Msgstate"}, new int[] {
            R.id.bs, R.id.si, R.id.msgStatus});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("first","1");
        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code fragment (I'm assuming its android).  My guess would be that the list fragments are constructed when the top level class is and the static variable is not being constructed first

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes its android :) i have posted the code... please let me know where have i gone wrong. I gess ur right... the listFragments are constructed before the static variable.. so what can i do ?? I'm new to android programming.. sorry if this a simple question :(